# Javascript Unexpected Token '+='

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am learning JS and I am using codepen.io to run couple of examples and do my practice there. So I wrote the following script which is using a Constructor notation for adding a Hotel Object. I also added the checkAvailability function to the Hotel Properties to  subtract the rooms that are booked - from the total rooms. Then I created a new variable to store the Hotel Details so I can print to screen the name of the hotel and rooms available. I am getting an error message saying that '+='  is unexpected token. Does anyone know why?

Thank you.

```
function Hotel(name, rooms, booked) {
  this.name = name;
  this.rooms = rooms;
  this.booked = booked;
  this.checkAvailability = function (){
    return this.rooms - this.booked;
  };
}
var alasiaHotel = new Hotel('Alasia', 50, 10);
var hotelDetails = alasiaHotel.name + ' rooms: ';
var hotelDetails += alasiaHotel.checkAvailability();
document.write(hotelDetails);
```

Comment: `var hotelDetails +=` should be `hotelDetails +=`.

Comment: I find this behaviour quite strange. var x=1; var x+=1; gives and error while var x=x+1; seems to be fine. Any explanations as to why?

Comment: sp00m answer fixed this guys. I should remove the var from the second hotelDetails .

Answer (score 1):

You can't `+=` in a variable definition, and you seem to have accidentally defined `hotelDetails` twice. If you remove the `var` from the `hotelDetails +=` statement, it should work.